# Assigning Binding to Attached Properties to hide a GridViewColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm

In WPF, using the MVVM model, I am struggling with what I believe is a binding issue.  I have a `ListView` designed to display a collection of objects.  The `ItemsSource` is bound to the collection and each `GridViewColumn` to seperate properties of that object.  This view (a `UserControl`) is generic across several tabs in a `TabControl` on the master window.  Each tab requires certain columns to be hidden (logic happens in the `ViewModel`).

I have created a Behaviors class to attach `DependecyProperties` for several things, including a property `IsHidden` for the `GridViewColumn`.  With this in mind, here's an example setup:

**Behavior Classes - minimized examples**

```
public static class LayoutColumn
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty HiddenProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "IsHidden",
      typeof(bool),
      typeof(LayoutColumn));

  public static bool GetIsHidden(DependencyObject obj)
  {
    return (bool)obj.GetValue(HiddenProperty);
  }

  public static void SetIsHidden(DependencyObject obj, bool isHidden)
  {
    obj.SetValue(HiddenProperty, isHidden);
  }

  public static bool IsHidden(this GridViewColumn column)
  {
    bool? isHidden = column.GetProperty<bool>(HiddenProperty);

    // Debug
    string format = "{0}.IsHidden = {1}";
    if (isHidden.HasValue)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(format, column.Header, isHidden.Value);
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine(format, column.Header, "Null");
    }

    return isHidden.HasValue && isHidden.Value;
  }

  private static T? GetProperty<T>(this GridViewColumn column, DependencyProperty dp) where T : struct
  {
    if (column == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("column");
    }

    object value = column.ReadLocalValue(dp);

    if (value != null && value.GetType() == dp.PropertyType)
    {
      return (T)value;
    }

    return null;
  }
} // end LayoutColumn class

public class LayoutManager
{
  // Methods and logic to enforce column min/max width, hidden, fixed, etc by attaching to the ListView and GridViewColumn event handlers.
}
```

**An example object class**

```
public class Example
{
  public string Foo { get; set; }
  public string Bar { get; set; }
  public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyDisplayViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private bool hidden;
  private ObservableCollection<Example> examples;

  ...

  public bool HideColumn
  {
    get 
    {
      return this.hidden;
    }

    set 
    {
      this.hidden = value;
      this.OnPropertyChanged("HideColumn");
    }
  }

  public ObservableCollection<Example> ExampleCollection
  {
    get 
    {
      return this.examples;
    }

    set 
    {
      this.examples = value;
      this.OnPropertyChanged("ExampleCollection");
    }
  }
}
```

**Some XAML**

```
<ListView
        Name="LogListView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleCollection}"
        ListViewBehaviors:LayoutManager.Enabled="{Binding AttachProperty}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn
                    Width="Auto"
                    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.MinWidth="40"
                    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.MaxWidth="200"
                    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.IsHidden="True"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Foo, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Header="Hidden Column"/>
                <GridViewColumn
                    Width="Auto"
                    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.MinWidth="74"
                    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.MaxWidth="200"
                    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.IsHidden="False"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bar, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Header="Visible Column"/>
                <GridViewColumn
                    Width="Auto"
                    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.IsFixed="True"
                    ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.IsHidden="{Binding Path=DataContext.HideColumn, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}},
                        Mode=OneWay}"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Baz, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Header="Dynamic Visibility">
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Demonstrated here, manually setting the attached property `IsHidden` to true or false works correctly to hide/show the associated column.  When `IsHidden` is null (the column doesn't have the attached behavior set) the expected behavior is for the column to show like normal.

**Problem**

The bound column *always* shows by default, which to me means `IsHidden` is not being set.  I feel like I'm close, but all my research results in examples doing what I've done here.  I'm fairly new to WPF, so I don't know what else to search for.

**Edit**

I've tried the following, but all failed:

```
AncestorType={x:Type ListView}
AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}
AncestorType={x:Type Window}
```

*What do I need to do to bind the* `GridViewColumn` *attached property to the* `ViewModel HideColumn` *property?*

Comment: Please share your behaviour. Also your viewmodel. May be you need to set the RelativeSource to Window or Usercontrol

Comment: @Ganesh I edited in the ViewModel.  I didn't add the behavior class since that would be a lot of bloat and I already know it works when manually setting true/false.  Also tested for `UserControl` and `Window` but sadly both failed.

Comment: Is the property IsHidden is DependencyProperty?

Comment: @Ganesh Yes.  I'll post a minimal version of my behavior class if others think it would really help.

Comment: Try this link. http://wickedflame-dev.blogspot.com/2012/05/seting-visibility-on-gridviewcolum-of.html.

Comment: Binding will work definitely (you can validate that by putting breakpoint on getter of HideColumn). Most likely logic of hiding doesn't work with binding in place. Can you post that code as well that how you are hiding the column?

Comment: @RohitVats The code hiding the column simply calls `bool? hidden = gridViewColumn.IsHidden();` Then if `hidden.HasValue && hidden.Value` is true, set the column width to 0 and disallow user interaction with the column header.  I've tried breakpoints in `HideColumn` getter and setter and in `LayoutColumn.IsHidden`.  The former two are hit when I set the dynamic column in the ViewModel.  The latter is hit for each GridViewColumn, printing in order (the debug Console.WriteLine) *True*, *False*, *Null*.  They seem bound, but the value isn't being set, else it would print *True*, *False*, *True*.

Comment: It might be possible that binding is not resolved till that time when you check for IsHidden(). Can you upload the code sample somewhere over the cloud if possbile?

Comment: Thanks @Ganesh for the link.  I struggled getting the answer from your link to work for me due to a lot of cancerous code from my previous attempts.  But once that was clean, it works nicely.

Comment: Also, thanks @RohitVats for pointing me in the direction of my logic.  Though the logic was sound, the logic was never applied when I thought it should have been and your suggestion led me to questions that made me run tests and checks for things I wouldn't have otherwise checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RohitVats pointed out, the main error was in my assumption that the code to hide the column was playing nicely.  I was relying on the `LayoutManager` to validate minimum and maximum widths - which (in `LayoutColumn class`) would return their values (adjusted to 0 if the column is hidden) and that in turn would resize the column.  The idea works but requires a little more. Much of what I needed to fix the issue came from [here](http://wickedflame-dev.blogspot.com/2012/05/seting-visibility-on-gridviewcolum-of.html) as suggested by @Ganesh.

**Cleaner XAML**

Through lots of `Console.WriteLine` and more debugging, I found that I was over complicating the binding.

```
ListViewBehaviors:LayoutColumn.IsHidden="{Binding HideColumn}"
```

**Additions to Behavior Class**

The change in XAML was only able to work once I made some changes to the `LayoutColumn` class setup by adding `PropertyMetadata` to `HiddenProperty` and another `DependencyProperty` for saving the previous-to-hidden width:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HiddenProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
  "IsHidden",
  typeof(bool),
  typeof(LayoutColumn)
  new PropertyMetadata(false, OnHiddenChanged));

public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibleWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
  "VisibleWidth",
  typeof(double),
  typeof(LayoutColumn),
  new UIPropertyMetadata(double.NaN));

public static double GetVisibleWidth(DependencyObject obj)
{
  return (double)obj.GetValue(VisibleWidthProperty);
}

public static void SetVisibleWidth(DependencyObject obj, double value)
{
  obj.SetValue(VisibleWidthProperty, value);
}

private static void OnHiddenChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  GridViewColumn column = dependencyObject as GridViewColumn;

  if (column != null)
  {
    if (e.Property == HiddenProperty)
    {
      bool hide = (bool)e.NewValue;

      if (hide)
      {
        SetVisibleWidth(column, column.Width);
        column.Width = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        column.Width = GetVisibleWidth(column);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And that's it!  I didn't use a `Converter` as shown in the link, since I'm handling a `bool` type on both ends of the binding, but it works just as well.  Hopefully this can be helpful to others.